# Use STUFF() on a result set coming from OPENJSON

Tags: json, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, stuff

I have a `ClassTable` as shown below with a `Languages` column in which the data is in JSON:

| ID | Title | Languages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Class1 | [{"ID": 1, "Name": "English"},{"ID": 2, "Name": "Hindi"}] |
| 2 | Class2 | [{"ID": 1, "Name": "Marathi"},{"ID": 2, "Name": "Telugu"}] |

and a `Master` table of `Languages` as

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | Hindi |
| 3 | Marathi |
| 4 | Telugu |

I need output as below

| ID | Title | LanguageIDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TestTitle1 | 1,2 |

I am trying to achieve this with `OPENJSON` to get data from `JSON` and then I am applying `STUFF()` to that data so that I would get comma separated LanguageIDs

This is the query, I have written but I am not getting the expected output

```
SELECT 
    A.ID,
    A.Title,
    LanguageIDs = STUFF ((SELECT CONCAT(',',A.ID)
                          FROM Master.Languages
                          WHERE ID IN (A.LanguageID)
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, SPACE(0))
FROM
    (SELECT 
         X.ID,
         X.Title,
         X.CreatedOn,
         B.ID as LanguageID
     FROM 
         ClassTable X
     CROSS APPLY  
         OPENJSON(Languages)
             WITH (ID INT '$.ID') as B
     WHERE 
         X.ID = 1) AS A
```

Can anybody tell me whats the mistake I am making? Or do I have to try a different approach for this problem?

Comment: `STUFF` has little to do with this; all it does here is remove the first character of a string. It doesn't make a delimited string (in the above that would be `FOR XML PATH` doing that). Considering you're on SQL Server 2017 though, why not use `STRING_AGG`?

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for the quick reply but I just realized that my server has SQL server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, It should work

```
 SELECT 
         X.ID,
         X.Title,
        (
        select cast(ID as varchar) +',' from OPENJSON(x.Languages)
             WITH (ID INT '$.ID')
             for xml path('')
        ) LanguageID
     FROM 
         ClassTable X where x.id=1
```

Comment: Did you mean to post a new answer? Why not [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65436534/edit) your existing one?

Comment: Yeah. The previous post was a different and I thought to notify the user to remove the ","

Comment: That feels like you should have posted a comment for the other answer then, if that was your intent.

Comment: Ok sure! Let me take a note of it. Thanks for letting me now on this

Comment: @SQLServerBuddy what if i want to add LanguageID in where Clause?